# Rails 4.2.0 - Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, asset-pipeline

In rails 4.2.0, I am using `paperclip` for file uploads. But it is throwing an error like `Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /files)`, how can I fix this issue?

When I run `gem list paperclip`, I got the list like below

```
paperclip (4.3.0, 4.2.2, 4.2.0, 2.4.5)
```

In controller, I have tried 2 ways, one is `@file = Asset.new(:document=>params[:asset][:document])` and the other way is

```
@file = Asset.new(user_params)

def user_params
  params.require(:asset).permit(:document)
end
```

In model,

```
attr_accessible :status, :document_file_name, :document_content_type, :document_file_size
attr_accessible :document

has_attached_file :document,
:url => '/files/:assetable_id/:basename.:extension',
:path => "/files/:assetable_id/:basename.:extension",
:storage => :filesystem
```

How can I solve this permission denied issue?

Comment: I think you are using aws-s3 as storage. If so then checkout your bucket accessibility for you on `s3`.

Comment: No. I am not using s3, I am trying to save it in localhost itself.

Comment: What is the full path of the folder that you are trying to save the files in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your path to the following (using `:rails_root`):

```
:path => ":rails_root/files/:assetable_id/:basename.:extension"
```

`rails_root` will give you the path to your app.

Comment: Did you try setting the path using `:rails_root` like this: `:path => ":rails_root/files/:assetable_id/:basename.:extension"` ?

Answer (score -1):

> To create Directory on local drive here is the running code-
>   To do so I was executing-

```
Dir.mkdir(Rails.root+ '/' + 'export')
```

But getting error as-
**Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Main_File**
*I know what was the reason, it was looking for Super User (`$ sudo`) permission but we can't provide machine password each time.*

> Following worked for me as required-

```
Dir.mkdir(File.join(Dir.home, ".foo"), 0700) #=> 0
```

To create and store the path in a variable-

```
main_file = File.exist?( File.join(Dir.home, "Main_File") ) ? File.join(Dir.home, "/Main_File") : Dir.mkdir( File.join(Dir.home, "Main_File") )
```

Above will create file if doesn't exist
If it exist will access that and store in variable `main_file`.

Thanks for [this link](https://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/mkdir/class)!

Hope will work for you !